# Custom UIScrollView scrollbar color?

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, uiscrollview, scrollbar

How do I change the default color of the UIScrollView scrollbar in XCode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't say, but since you're using UIKit, I assume you'd be developing for iOS.

```
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
```

Replace `UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite` to anything from [this typedef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW5).

Comment: Probably not the exact thing he is looking for but that's the closest one will get with the provided framework.